# Laravel 5.8 Schema adding foreign key not working

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-schema-builder

I'm trying to create foreign keys in Laravel 5.8 and when I migrate my table using Artisan the foreign key not set. In the `cities` table and `provinces` table, all id fields are unsigned integers. I'm working with wamp64 on Windows 10.

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('province_id')->unsigned();
        // table Foreign Key
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->foreign('province_id')->references('id')->on('provinces');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you have already `users` rows within your `users database table`.
to achieve that you should make these new fields `city_id` and  `province_id`  as `nullable`  as default value.

so your migration should be like below :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

         // I have added here nullable for both city_id and province_id

        $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('province_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        // table Foreign Key
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
        $table->foreign('province_id')->references('id')->on('provinces');
    });
}
```